# sum and order by on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables. The first:

```
files
+----+--------+----------+
| id | userid | filesize |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |       11 |
|  2 |      1 |       22 |
|  3 |      2 |        5 |
|  4 |      2 |       24 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

and a simple users table (username, id…).

I want to sum up the all filesizes for each user and order by these sizes.
The expected result is:

User with id 1: 33 byte,

User with id 2: 29 byte

and so on.

I already tried SQL-Query with Join and multi-table-querys.
Is this even possible with SQL only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT userid,SUM(filesize) as TotalSize
FROM files
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY SUM(filesize) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for this impulse. Finally I Use this: SELECT users.username, users._id, user_ID, SUM(size) as totalSize FROM files INNER JOIN users ON users._id = files.user_ID GROUP BY user_ID ORDER BY SUM(size) DESC